# how to get handle of created mdi child?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Thansk!!
I wish get the handle of mdi child in the clientWndProc, using WM_MDICREATE message

```
procedure TFrmMain.ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
Hwnd : HWND;
procedure Default;
begin
 with Message do
  Result := CallWindowProc(FClientWndProc, ClientHandle, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

begin
case Message.Msg of
  WM_MDICREATE:
   begin
    hwnd := Message.LParam; //dont' work
    hwnd := TWMMDICreate(Message).MDICreateStruct^.lparam; //don't work
   Default;
   end;

  end;

  inherited ClientWndProc(Message);
  end;
```

I want Bind the next proceddure (ChildProc) when started a MDICHILD, into the ClientWndProc Procedure of MainForm

```
    function childProc(hwnd: HWND;  msg, wParam,lParam: LongInt): LongInt; stdcall;
    begin
     if msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND then
      begin
       CallWindowProc(p,hwnd,msg,wparam,lparam);
        if WParam = SC_MINIMIZE then
          //do something
       end;

    result := CallWindowProc(p,hwnd,msg,wparam,lparam);

    end;
```

I need the handle of new chid form ,Something like that

```
        P := Pointer(SetWindowLong(ActiveMDIChild.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, integer(@Child)));
```

Comment: Surely thats because while you have received the MDICREATE message, its not made yet, thats the before its made, so there is no handle..

Comment: Why don't you call the 'inherited' first, then get your handle from 'Message.Result', then do what you have to do with the handle, and then 'exit' in your WM_MDICREATE case as have been told in the answer. It would satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I can't understand your edit. You've already been told the answer.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644913.aspx) for `WM_MDICREATE`:

> #### Return value
>
> Type: **HWND**
>
> If the message succeeds, the return value is the handle to the new child window.
>
> If the message fails, the return value is NULL.

So, the answer is the window handle the value that the window procedure returns. Read it out of `Message.Result` after you have called the inherited window procedure.

If you want the window handle before the window has been created, well, you are out of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot! it's perfect you answer

```
  procedure TMain.ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
   begin

      case Message.Msg of

         WM_MDICREATE:
          begin
          inherited ClientWndProc(Message);
          with Message do
          FindControl(Result).Tag := SetWindowLong(Result, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(@MDIChildProc));
          Exit; 
          end;

       end;

   end;
```

Comment: You should indeed accept an answer. My answer is correct and tells you what you needed to do, expressed in this code.